# Is it possible to reverse a HMAC hash with Python?

Tags: python, hash, hmac, pycryptodome

I discovered the Hash-based Message Authentication Code (HMAC) and how to use it with a SHA-256 hash for example.
I follow that link https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/hash/hmac.html.

So I gave it a try and understood how to generate a HMAC, see the snippet below :

```
mySecret = b"....."
h = HMAC.new(mySecret, digestmod = SHA256)
h.update(b"hello")
print (h.hexdigest()) # 1bef439a8c4fe14770480ebe819cb2e7d5cd68ca4ccf4b3c1f248fc2a525b0a9
```

Everything is ok on this part.
Then I searched how I could do to reverse it and get `mySecret` back. And I must admit I have no ideas to make it.
It it possible to do it ?

Thanks.

Comment: you seem to misunderstand something, HMACs are not reversible

Comment: Its possible to guess `mySecret`, but probably an unfeasible algorithm.

Comment: You have to use a brute-force technique, trying all possible values of mySecret and running it through the HMAC until you find the one value that results in an HMAC of `1bef439a8c4fe1477...`.